# How does Tensorflow's reduce_sum work in a loop?

Tags: tensorflow

I cannot understand the working of reduce_sum when the optimizer is run in a loop.

I have 30 samples in my `train_x` and `train_y` lists. I run my optimizer in a loop by feeding one sample from both at an iteration. My cost function computes the sum of the difference of predicted and actual values for all samples using the tensorflow's `reduce_sum` method. According to the graph the optimzer depends on the cost function and so the cost will be computed for every `x` and `y`. I need to know whether the `reduce_sum` will wait for all the 30 samples or take one sample (`x`, `y`) at a time. Here `n_samples` is 30. I also need to know whether the `weights` and `bias` will be updated for each epoch or for each `x` and `y`.

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

W = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(), name='weights')
B = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(), name='bias')

pred = X * W + B

cost = tf.reduce_sum((pred - Y) ** 2) / (2 * n_samples)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sesh:
    sesh.run(init)

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for x, y in zip(train_x, train_y):
            sesh.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})

        if not epoch % 20:
            c = sesh.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_x, Y: train_y})
            w = sesh.run(W)
            b = sesh.run(B)
            print(f'epoch: {epoch:04d} c={c:.4f} w={w:.4f} b={b:.4f}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to know whether the reduce_sum will wait for all the 30 samples or take one sample (x, y) at a time.

`tf.reduce_sum` is an operation and as such it does not have any implicit mutable state. The result of `tf.reduce_sum` is fully defined by the model parameters (`W` and `B`) and the placeholder values explicitly provided in the `feed_dict` argument to the `sess.run(cost, feed_dict={...})` call.

If you would like to aggregate the value of a metric across all batches check out [`tf.metrics`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics):

```
y_pred = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
mse, update_op = tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
init = tf.local_variables_initializer()  # MSE state is local!
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

# Update the metric and compute the value after the update.
sess.run(update_op, feed_dict={y_pred: [0.0], y_true: [42.0]})  # => 1764.0
# Get current value.
sess.run(mse)  # => 1764.0
```

> I also need to know whether the weights and bias will be updated for each epoch or for each x and y.

Each `sess.run(optimizer, ...)` call will compute the gradients of the trainable variables and apply these gradients to the variable values. See [`GradientDescentOptimizer.minimize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/GradientDescentOptimizer#minimize).

Comment: Do the cost be computed for every `x` and `y` instead for every epoch?. Then what's the use of `reduce_sum` if the cost is computed for every `x` and `y`.

Comment: The purpose of `tf.reduce_sum` is to sum the tensor along the specified axis. It is conceptually similar to [`np.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html). As noted above, if you are looking for aggregate metrics, use `tf.metrics.*`.